# autodesk forge model derivatives testing api

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'd like to use the Autodesk Forge model derivative API, but I'd also like to write some integration tests to check I use the api properly.
If I use the regular API, as far as I understand - I will pay for each "conversion".

Is there a testing api for the model derivatives that I can use that gets and returns dummy data without using my cloud credits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we do have dev and staging environments with a thorough integration testing, I'm afraid these are not available to external customers.

You could store the SVF output generated by the Model Derivative service, and use that in your tests instead.

Comment: Ok, but this won't help me with integration tests where I check that I send proper requests to your service and handle responses correctly.

Comment: Right, like I said we don't have a publicly available Model Derivative API you could use without cloud credits, so you'll need to mock this part of your integration tests.